# Sobre as applets que serão descontinuadas, utilizei java web start do netbeans mas não funcionou com o navegador chrome

Tags: java

Eu realmente preciso saber a totalidade para usar o java web start plugin livre, pois sei que tem soluçãi; Qual seria a melhor técnica para lançar applets no navegador chrome?

Eu gerei no netbeans os arquivos launch.html, teste.jar e o teste2.jnlp. Mesmo assim nada de funcionarn no chrome.

Segue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:8080/hello" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>appletJavaWS</title>
    <vendor>aline.gonzaga</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>appletJavaWS</description>
    <description kind="short">appletJavaWS</description>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.5+"/>
  <jar href="appletJavaWS.jar" main="true"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="Principal">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

O launch.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</h3>
    <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton("launch.jnlp")
    </script>
    <!-- Or use the following link element to launch with the application -->
    <!--
    <a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>
    -->
    </body>
</html>
```

E o jar. Alguém me dá uma luz? Java web start é muito novo para mim.

Comment: Chrome não suporte mais a NPAPI, que é a tecnologia que o java usava para seu plugin. Java web start na verdade baixa um arquivo que executa externo ao navegador, logo, é independente do navegador que o usuario estiver usando.

Comment: crossbrowser como eu aplico isso na minha applet?

Comment: Applet não é java web, são tecnologias diferentes em sua execução. O applet é executado pelo NPAPI, que foi descontinuado na maioria dos navegadores. Ou você migra pra java web ou javafx, ou corre risco de ficar na mao.

Comment: sim. É isso que quero entender melhor eu estou utilizando o java web start fiz esse mini teste no netbeans. Tudo o que um java web start precisa para ser lançado no navegador eu fiz mas nao funciona no chrome de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Vc sabe de alguma coisa? Se falta algo? eu sei que applet nao é um jws eu só quero lançar a applet através dessa tecnologia.

Comment: No console aparece que erro quando você clica no link?

Comment: erro no console do netbeans? Eu não reparei nisso porque eu gerei uns arquivos e estou rodando externamente do netbeans fiz o deploy com o tomcat da app, ou seja estou rodando como localhost

Comment: Erro no console do navegador Chrome, abre o console na página e depois clica no link =)

Comment: Vou fazer isso agora. Mas fica aí, não suma não.

Comment: Consegui! \o/ vamos comemorar comigo?